# How can I use gtk_message_dialog_new() without triggering "GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent."

Tags: c, gtk, x11, gtk3, gnome

Here is the code:

```
int Notice(char *title, char *message,  GtkButtonsType buttons)
{   
    int response;
    GtkWidget *notice = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL,
        GTK_DIALOG_MODAL, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
        buttons,
        "%s", title);

    // tried to fix the error here, but see the error below:
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(notice, main_window); 
    
    gtk_message_dialog_format_secondary_text(GTK_MESSAGE_DIALOG(notice), "%s", message);

    response = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(notice));

    gtk_widget_destroy(notice);

    return response;
}
```

But I get this:

```
Gtk-Message: 16:55:19.022: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

My fix in the comments creates this compiler warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_window_set_transient_for’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  gtk_window_set_transient_for(notice, main_window);
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Pass `main_window` as the first argument to `gtk_message_dialog_new` and eliminate the `gtk_window_set_transient_for` call?

Comment: @CraigEstey, that works but I had to cast because main_window is a GtkWidget* from `main_window = create_main_window( &main_window_builder );`, which is actually defined as `GtkWindow` in the `.glade` file.  When I cast I get this very strange compiler error: `note: expected ‘struct GtkWindow *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkWindow *’`.  How do I cast from GtkWidget to GtkWindow?

Comment: Oh, this did it. GTK_WINDOW(main_window)

Comment: Kinda figured there was a macro/function to get the window for a [given] widget. My GTK is a bit rusty, so I couldn't think of it off the top of my head. _Side note:_ WA1NIO

Comment: `GTK_WINDOW()`  is a good GTK feature which performs a typecast check at runtime. One should never use the **C** casting style aka `(GtkWindow*)window` because the compiler assumes that you know what you do, and if the window is not a GtkWindow things are going to be messy.

Comment: @CraigEstey, I wonder if SE counts as a QSO! This code is going into xnec2c, we're adding support for LAPACK, OpenBLAS, and Intel KML which is 2-3x faster than the old NEC2 code.  https://www.qsl.net/5b4az/pkg/nec2/xnec2c/doc/xnec2c.html